# How to sum a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am a new learner in Matlab and now want to add up a cell of column elements in Matlab, somehow "sum" function didn't work and it shows "Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'", is there anyone know how to do it? MANY THANKS!:)

my data is like this:
'218148'
'106856'
'255673'
'156279'
'175589'
'310762'
'87128'
'123339'
'149070'
'104556'
'206346'
'216278'
'235786'

Comment: Can you show us an example of your data. You'll have to first convert it to a numeric datatype before summing it.

Comment: Yeah, the array is numerical and something like this:

'218148'
'106856'
'255673'
'156279'
'175589'
'310762'
'87128'
'123339'
'149070'
'104556'
'206346'
'216278'
'235786'
'236087'
'99137'
'123335'
'130021'
'101655'
'98159'
'102047'
'824411'
'63290'

Comment: Yea those are not numeric, they are strings. See @Sardar_Usama's answer below.

Comment: I deleted my answer. See @EBH's answer

Answer (score 3):

Your cells are strings so you first have to convert them to numeric:

```
C = { '218148' '106856' '255673' '156279' '175589' '310762' '87128'...
    '123339' '149070' '104556' '206346' '216278' '235786' '236087'...
    '99137' '123335' '130021' '101655' '98159' '102047' '824411' '63290'};
Csum = sum(str2double(C));
```

the result:

```
Csum =
     4123952
```

Comment: But it shows error:Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 83)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

Error in SNL (line 7)
s=sum(cell2mat(Shop_MYR));

Comment: Oh I didn't know `str2double` could be directly  applied on cells. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can call the content of your cells like this:

```
your_cell{:}
```

If all values are numeric, you can then group this result as a vector:

```
[your_cell{:}]
```

you can then easily sum this result:

```
sum([your_cell{:}])
```

A small example:

```
c{1} = 1;
c{2} = 3;
c{3} = 6;
sum([c{:}])
```

result:

```
ans =
    10
```